# CFLAGS in bitbake recipe are not used during cross compile

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to write a bitbake recipe for an old project that has redefinition errors when compiling with a more modern gcc version. To get around that I included `CFLAGS:append = "-fcommon"` in the bitbake recipe (.bb file), however compilation still fails when I try `bitbake myrecipe` as the gcc command does not include the additional flag from the .bb file.

When I run bitbake with the `-v` flag `-fcommon` is not in the gcc command but when I look at the `run.do_compile` file I see `export CFLAGS= "... -fcommon"`. I also tried using `TARGET_CFLAGS` in the .bb file with the same results. What do I need to to to make sure my flag is used in the gcc call when I `bitbake myrecipe`?

Edit: Here are the recipe files

- myrecipie.inc

```
SUMMARY = "My summary"
HOMEPAGE = "mysrcurl.com"
SECTION = "base"

DEPENDS = "ncurses"

CFLAGS:append = "-fcommon"

do_compile() {
  oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${bindir}
  install -m 0755 ${BP} ${D}${bindir}
}
```

- myrecipie_1.0.0.bb

```
require myrecipie.inc

LICENSE = "GPL-2.0-only"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://gpl.txt;md5=393a5ca445f6965873eca0259a17f833"

SRC_URI = "mysrcurl.com/${BPN}/${PV}/${BPN}-${PV}.tar.gz"

SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "bfbc5c378704d9cf5e7fed288dac88859149bee5ed0850175759d310b61fd30b"
```

Edit 2: I tried using `EXTRA_OEMAKE:append = " CFLAGS='-fcommon'"` and that let me get past the compile command but then the flags from the project `Makefile` are not present in the `gcc` call but the project does seem to compile correctly. I'm not happy with this as the solution as I want both the flags from the project `Makefile` with `-fcommon` added.

Comment: Can you post your recipe content ?

Comment: Added the .inc and .bb files to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbake will export `CFLAGS` with the content of `TARGET_CFLAGS`.

So, at first, add `-fcommon` to `TARGET_CFLAGS`

Now, when `CFLAGS` is an environment variable, then `Makefile` will see it.

The problem is whithin the `Makefile` itself:

If `CFLAGS` is not assigned with `+=` then it will be overriden by the `CFLAGS` exported by Bitbake.

So check your `Makefile` and it you find `CFLAGS =` then you need to create a patch for it and add it to `SRC_URI`.

**SIDE NOTE**: No need to override `do_compile` if you just want to run `make` as the default `do_compile` does run `oe_runmake`.